# CSS Long Table Issue in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I am having an issue with long table in IE based browser.

Basically I have table with large number of columns, so it is scroll-able in X-Direction which is fine. But when I scrolls table horizontally in IE 10, some random vertical bars appears on table as shown in image.(In the region that becomes visible by scrolling). Please observe the position on scrollbar.

When I click on any column, it disappears and renders fine. I think think it is some browser related issue., as it works perfectly in all other browser.

But is there any method I can solve this?

I am using Twitter's Bootstrap.

Here is the CSS code for table:

```
table.query_result_table {
    width: 2500px;
    max-width: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Note:** I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin for this table.

[image]

Comment: seems to be rendering issue on your pc, did you try it on a different pc?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, I checked on multiple PC's. In all of them IE shows above problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to hide the artifacts that show up in webkit browsers when using jQuery animate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865310/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-artifacts-that-show-up-in-webkit-browsers-when-using)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865310/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-artifacts-that-show-up-in-webkit-browsers-when-using) refers to webkit based browsers, but maybe it will work in IE as well.

Try capturing the scrolling event, and after it ends, scroll down 1px and back up 1px.